# Rnaapp in Windows mobile 6.5 (Dialup connection)

Tags: windows-mobile

In Windows mobile 5 I had a link (lnk file) wich cointained : 255#"\windows\rnaapp.exe"  -e"test". Using that lnk file I was able to dial a connection that I named "test" (In WM 5.0).

Now I got a Samsung bt7610 with WM 6.5, and when I use my lnk file, it frezzes pop-up windows and makes no connection.

My guess is that there was a change in a rnapp.exe or somthing like that. Can anyboady help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the number before the `#` to be the actual length of the command. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx).

```
30#"\windows\rnaapp.exe" -e"test"
```